# Accessing files in a folder via Drive API?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I am trying to access some files from my Google Drive, via the Drive API. I followed the tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/js) , to do so in Javascript. Now, simply calling the function `listFiles()` works correctly, and prints all the files in my drive, along with their ID's.

But, I want to access all the files found in certain folders. Looking online, the drive API has such a function called `retrieveAllFilesInFolder(folderId, callback)`

It is defined as follows:

```
function retrieveAllFilesInFolder(folderId, callback) {
  var retrievePageOfChildren = function(request, result) {
    request.execute(function(resp) {
      result = result.concat(resp.items);
      var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;
      if (nextPageToken) {
        request = gapi.client.drive.children.list({
          'folderId' : folderId,
          'pageToken': nextPageToken
        });
        retrievePageOfChildren(request, result);
      } else {
        callback(result);
      }
    });
  }
  var initialRequest = gapi.client.drive.children.list({
      'folderId' : folderId
    });
  retrievePageOfChildren(initialRequest, []);
}
```

When, I call the code in my local server (passing in a string ID of a folder), I get the following error: `quickstart.html:73 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined`, implying there are no children of this folder. I know this to be false. Is there a particular reason that this is happening.

Comment: What version of Drive API are you using? As in Drive API V3(latest), to list children of folder the rest call is changed to **files.list with ?q='parent_id'+in+parents**  Check [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration#methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so directly [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list#try-it), via the Google Developer's website.